# How to render angular template in ajax

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am having on angular page.
Page1 : 
In which configuration is

```
.when('/Test/:empId', {
        templateUrl:'/Templates/test.html',
        controller: 'TestController'
    })

.when('/Test/:depId', {
            templateUrl:'/Templates/test1.html',
            controller: 'Test1Controller'
        })
```

Then i have another page

Page 2: 
This page is normal mvc razor page having button

```
Button1
```

On click of that button i want to show modal which contain
Page1

So i wrote

```
                $.ajax({
                        url: '/Templates/test.html',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (responce) {
                            var elem = angular.element(responce);
                            $('#testModalBody').html(elem);
                            $('#testModal').modal('show');
                            //console.log('test responce');
                        }
                    });
```

I am just getting html response, it does not execute 'TestController'
So the scope variables are not getting values declared in TestController, and not able to see data html pages. Just see static html template.

Comment: try to use `$compile(angular.element()($scope))`

Comment: @JayantPatil : getting angular.element(...) is not a function error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $.ajax, you should **use $http service** of Angular JS.

Instead of doing like this  $('#testModalBody'), you can use ng-bind-html.

To bind HTML please read below link.

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp

Comment: I  want to keep 'testBody' independent from angular. I want to use the template like partial view.

Comment: Post your complete code of js. Where have you written $ ajax code in your file?